# Python Bokeh Stacked Bar Chart - How to display data label inside bars?

Tags: python-2.7, label, bokeh, stacked-chart

I am currently using this example to create bar chart with Bokeh: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.0/docs/gallery/stacked_bar_chart.html

Everything works so far, however I couldn't find a way to add data value to each bar like this chart: 
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/elements.html

The Bokeh.Charts.Bar class does not have the .text() function like Bokeh.Plotting.Figure. Is there anyway for me to add in the data like the elements chart to the bar chart? I have tried digging around all the codes below the classes and could not find any solution. Help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments:

First, in the near future (possibly in `0.12` but not certainly) the `Chart` class will be made a subclass of `Figure` so that all of the "glyph methods" like `Figure.text` will also work on charts as well.

Regardless of that, `Chart` is always a subclass of `Plot` which means that you can use "low level" glyph objects and `Plot.add_glyph` anytime. This looks basically like:

```
from bokeh.models.glyphs import  Text

text_glyph = Text(x="x", y="y", x_offset=10, text="foo")
text_renderer = plot.add_glyph(data_source, text_glyph)
```

A complete example (from version `0.11.1`) using the `Text` glyph [can be seen here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.11.1/examples/models/sprint.py).

Finally, just today a new PR was merged to add a proper `Label` annotation to Bokeh, that will make this kind of thing even easier. You can see the PR here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/4106

This work will be part of the `0.12` release.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer, bigreddot!